# Phaser3 Game Canvas Responsive

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I know starting from phaser 3 there is a ScaleManager, to do `Phaser.Scale.FIT`, however it not the responsive I wish for. My canvas mainly focus on the center of screen, so when resizing the browser, I want the canvas is fit the parent, and it is ok to crop out left and right content

```
const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    backgroundColor: '#282c34',
    parent: 'phaser-container',
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    },
    scene: [SplashScreen, GameScreen],
}
  
const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
export default game;

// Game Screen
create(){
    this.scale.on('resize', this.resize, this);
}

resize (gameSize: { width: any; height: any; }, baseSize: any, displaySize: any, resolution: any){
    this.cameras.resize(displaySize._parent._width, displaySize._parent._height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the use case, if I understand it correct you could use `mode: Phaser.Scale.HEIGHT_CONTROLS_WIDTH` *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scale.html#.HEIGHT_CONTROLS_WIDTH__anchor))*. But since your width is variable, this makes the most sense.

It could look something like this.

**html:**

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="parent"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

 #parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80vh;
 }
```

**js:**

```js
const config = {
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.HEIGHT_CONTROLS_WIDTH,
        parent: 'parent',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    scene: [...]
};
```

This could work for your own problem.